# Pull force of neodymium magnets - is there a way to be more realistic?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a mirror attached to a 360 degrees swivel/tilt base. The mirror with the base weights 1 lbs.

I glued a N52 round magnet on the base, and another magnet on the wall. Each magnet measures: 1.25 inch diameter and 1/8 (0.125) inch high.

According to the research I did, that should provide a pull force of more than 45 lbs. Differently than in standard tests, my magnets don't even have a metal object between them, they contact with each other directly. So, these magnetic should provide way more than enough to hold this mirror on the wall.

However, in reality this was absolutely not enough. The mirror doesn't stay.

Even being *very* conservative to the magnet pull force, it means that this computed 45 lbs pull force has been unable to even hold a 1 lbs piece securely.

I understand I should not expect a 49 lbs force (I did not), I didn't even expect a 20 lbs force, but the fact it doesn't even hold a 1 lbs object is very disappointing, and I don't know how to estimate how many discs are necessary anymore. It also makes the pull force found online very untrustworthy.

Is there a way to guess, estimate better what kind and how many magnets are necessary for a given application?

Comment: Pull strength vs shear strength are likely different.

Comment: igorjrr, Jon Custer is correct.  If you try to pull your two magnets straight apart, they will resist to a high degree.  However, if you try to slide one magnet past the other, they will resist to a much lesser degree, and in fact, that is how I typically separate small diameter neodymium magnets.  To fix your problem, get thicker magnets, and make sure that you glue the wall magnet to something that is stronger than dry wall (aka gypsum board or sheet rock).

Comment: Or add a ridge around one of the magnets to prevent sliding.

Comment: They are not sliding down. What is happening is that the top part of the magnets are separating first, bringing the mirror down. What puzzles me is that a pull strength of 45 lbs ends up being unable to hold a 1 lbs mirror on the wall :/. @DavidWhite a thicker magnet would help here?

Comment: @igorjrr, my best guess is that a thicker magnet would work.  However, based on your description of the failure mode, I suspect that your mirror and base are located several inches from the wall when they fall off.  This means that torque is unseating your magnet.  Please provide a drawing of your mirror, and indicate how far the mirror can be extended before it falls.